# How to call instance methods on the nested Serializer with django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've got two models I'm trying to nest together. `Timesheet` and `Invoice`

My `InvoiceSerializer` looks something like this:

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    billable_timesheets = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 
    total_hours_and_cost = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = (
            "hours",
            "hour_cost",
            "billable_timesheets",
            "total_hours_and_cost", 
            ...

            )

    def get_total_hours_and_cost(self, obj):
        return obj.hours * obj.hour_cost

    def get_billable_timesheets(self, obj):
        """Getting all timesheets for selected billable period"""
        timesheets = obj.project.timesheets.filter(<queryset here>)
        return TimesheetSerializer(timesheets, many=True).data
```

This works fine and all - I can define MethodFields and the correct JSON is returned, great. However, I got a method on my child model (in this case, the `Timesheet` model) that I need to access and run some calculations on. I'm getting the data necessary via `get_billable_timesheets`, and now I need to run a method on my `Timesheet model` called `total_duration()`. Whenever I try to do something along the lines of

```
timesheets = self.get_billable_timesheets(obj)
hours = 0
for timesheet in timesheets:
    hours += timesheet.total_duration()
```

I get:
`AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'total_duration'`

What I don't understand is that I'm actually serializing the data already through the `get_billable_timesheets` method - why am I still receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution for my case was to not return a serialized version of the timesheets, (e.g instead of `return TimesheetSerializer(timesheets, many=True).data`

I just did `return timesheets` → did my calculations needed and then serialized the timesheet:

```
    def get_billable_timesheets(self, obj):
        """Getting all timesheets for selected billable period"""
        timesheets = obj.project.timesheets.filter(<queryset here>)
        return timesheets # instead of a serialized version
```

Answer (score 1):

The timesheet in your for loop is an ordered dict instance, since get_billable_timesheets returns serialized data.

A workaround can be,

```
timesheets = self.get_billable_timesheets(obj)
hours = 0
for timesheet in timesheets:
    timesheet_id = timesheet.get('id')
    timesheet_obj = Timesheet.objects.get(id=timesheet_id)
    hours += timesheet_obj.total_duration()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I actually managed to find a work around by not serializing the timesheet → doing the calculations needed → serialize the timesheet